# How to implement a ControlValueAccessor to convert a property from num to String and vice versa

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I am attempting to bind a property of type num. But angular2 complains that the attempated conversion (num to string) is illegal. I have seen where ControlValueAccessor could be used but lacks the knowledge to do so?

```
     <input type="number"
     min = "0"
     max = "120"
     #yearsCtrl = "ngForm"
     [ngFormControl] = "ageForm.controls['yearsCtrl']"
     [(ngModel)] = "age.years"
     id = "years">
```

Does anyone knows how to use a ControlValueAccessor to convert ngModel num (age.years) to String for display in the browser and convert String back to num for storage?

I don't really want to have to convert my model properties to string to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you try with a pipe ?

Comment: @Julien Alary: Yes. Resulted in error. But the pipe is a one-way conversion. How would the String -> number conversion occur when the model is update?

Answer (score 0):

If you define the model field of the input as type `num` it works by default. `int` should be avoided in the browser anyway for values that are passed from the browser.

Comment: num does not work. The error is as before `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 's'.`

Comment: Doesn't look like the change from `int` to `num` was taken. I built a sample project and it worked fine. Angular2 contains a `NumberValueAccessor` and a breakpoint showed it's convert function was called and the value was assigned to the `num` field.

Comment: Do you use sn `<input>` field or some other element?

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer: Please see the edit with the input type (=number) above. What does the 'sn' means. Could you add your example that works in the answer.

Comment: I'll publish my sample tomorrow. My computer is currently out of order.

Comment: Just a gentle reminder about the sample to be published. Thanks

Comment: Right, still mostly fighting with my new PC :-/ https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/dart_playground/blob/dcc91f784bae100d815a9098f9ef72f3468c5d96/angular2/so35443309_custom_value_accessor/lib/app_element.dart#L15-L15